# Axis grid is not displayed when employing explicitly grid-containing style with matplotlib.pyplot.style.use('seaborn-whitegrid')

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, plot, seaborn

Even though I set the plotting style in every plotting script manually right at the beginning of the code, directly after importing the modules, the *figure-plotting-style* to [seaborn-whitegrid](https://seaborn.pydata.org/tutorial/aesthetics.html#seaborn-figure-styles), the resulting figures comprise the plain `matplotlib.pyplot` standard white background without grid display, e.g. like this graph:
[image: Example_output_graph.png]

Therefore, I assume that setting the style has no effect on my scripts, but I can't tell where it goes wrong, or where the style changes back to default. It'd be practical to print out the currently active plotting style at any given point, e.g. during a debugging session.

This is how I set my plotting style:

```
import .....
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import .....

# * Set the matplotlib.pyplot default template (plotting style and background) *
plt.style.use('seaborn-whitegrid')

# Start of script #
...
```

I even inserted the line `plt.style.use('seaborn-whitegrid')` in my plotting-submodules, which the main script calls, but it doesn't seem to have an effect on the output.

**EDIT on additional trials:**

According to what was suggested below by *@Bernardo Trindade*, I replaced `plt.style.use` with `mpl.style.use`:

```
# * Set the matplotlib.pyplot default template (plotting style and background) *
mpl_plt_default_template = 'seaborn-whitegrid'
import matplotlib as mpl
mpl.style.use(mpl_plt_default_template)
```

What I also tried is [temporary styling](https://matplotlib.org/3.3.3/tutorials/introductory/customizing.html#temporary-styling), but with no avail either:

```
# Set plotting style
with plt.style.context('seaborn-whitegrid'):

# * Instantiate figure
fig, axs = plt.subplots(rows, cols, figsize=(width, height))
....
```

All of the above has not lead to any difference in the output graphs; still showing the plain standard matplotlib background without grid etc.

---

**System specifics:**

Lubuntu 20.04 LTS,
python 3.9x,
VS Code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found the culprit:

```
ax.grid(which='both', alpha=1)
```

Previously, this line never caused an issue, the grids were displayed just fine.
By contrast, now this setting the grid like this renders the grid invisible.

---

**1) CONCLUSION (short answer)**

The easiest way to make it work, i.e. safeguard that the grid appears, is setting either the parameter `b` to `True` like so:

```
ax.grid(b=True, which='both', alpha=1)
```

Alternatively, the kwarg `visible` can be set to `True` like so:

```
ax.grid(which='both', alpha=1, visible=True)
```

I recommend using `visible=True` since the naming of the *kwarg* is more intuitive as to what it actually does, compared to the optional parameter merely called `b`.

---

**2) ELABORATE ANSWER**

The following information is based on the [official matplotlib docs](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.grid.html#matplotlib-axes-axes-grid):

The allegedly optional parameter `b` must be set manually to `True` or `False`, because otherwise, it'll be set to `None` in this context,
even though the current docs state:

> b : bool or None, optional
> Whether to show the grid lines. If any kwargs are supplied, it is assumed you want the grid on and b will be set to True.
>
> ```
> If b is None and there are no kwargs, this toggles the visibility of the lines.
> ```

**NOTE** on boolean parameter "b":
I've tried both `True` and `False` to find out that even `False` delivers a proper grid, which is counterintuitive.

On the contrary, when put explicitely to `None`, which is equivalent to passing nothing, the grid won't appear:

```
ax.grid(b=None, which='both', alpha=1)
```

As mentioned before, the grid is invisible in this context also with the following, which was my original code line:

```
ax.grid(which='both', alpha=1)
```

Skimming through the `**kwargs` revealed an extra *visibility kwarg* called [visible](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.artist.Artist.set_visible.html#matplotlib.artist.Artist.set_visible):

**NOTE** on naming of the *visibility kwarg* in its docs:

> Artist.set_visible(self, b)[source]

It is called `b`, just like the

> optional parameter

of ax.grid().

I confirmed that they actually do the same thing.

The grid appears, when putting the visible-kwarg to `True`:

```
ax.grid(b=None, which='both', alpha=1, visible=True)
```

When put to contradictory values, the following error is thrown:

```
ValueError: 'b' and 'visible' specify inconsistent grid visibilities
```

This error is caused when employing one of the following two possibilities:

```
ax.grid(b=False, which='both', alpha=1, visible=True)
ax.grid(b=True, which='both', alpha=1, visible=False)
```

**Eventually, to make the grid appear successfully**, set either the parameter `b` to `True` like so:

```
ax.grid(b=True, which='both', alpha=1)
```

Alternatively, the kwarg `visible` can be set to `True` like so:

```
ax.grid(which='both', alpha=1, visible=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's a variable that stores the name of the stylesheet currently used, as all the style information is kept in a large dictionary whose values are simply updated when calling `matplotlib.style.use()`.

Have you tried:

```py
import matplotlib as mpl
mpl.style.use('seaborn-whitegrid')
```

Comment: Thanks for your input. I've replaced this in all my python-scripts, but it has not made any difference. If you have more ideas, they'll be welcome.

Comment: Have you tried a context based approach, such as proposed here? https://matplotlib.org/3.3.3/tutorials/introductory/customizing.html#temporary-styling

Comment: I've just tried it, it doesn't make a difference in the output though. I'm going to attach one of my output graphs to my original post. Somehow, always the matplotlib - default plotting background style is employed. I don't understand why it doesn't work anymore.

Comment: Anyways, thanks for your help. Finally, I found the solution, see my answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65567436/12298276

Comment: I'm glad you figured it out and thanks for posting the answer.